# Calling custom fields for pages (not posts)

Tags: custom-field, pages, loop

I'm trying to place a small code in my template `header.php` file. I want to get a custom field value.

I'm trying to call custom fields from current page **outside** of loop, btw.

I have no problem doing this when I need to get custom field values from posts, but I can't seem to do this for pages.

Here is my code:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'teaser-text', true);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried changing `$wp_query->post->ID;` to this `$wp_query->page->ID;` to no success.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
get_metadata('post', $postid, 'teaser-text, true);
```

these two actually same. should not make any difference. earlier i gave wrong arguments. var_dump() will show you what it is actually getting. please make sure, the ID is correct, 'teaser-text' exists. You can also try using some other meta name (for testing purpose only).

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to do it. I still cannot get it to work though. I'm even hardcoding the page id into the arguments.

Comment: sorry to hear but what problem you are getting? i've checked this and working at my end. try var_dump(). does 'teaser-text' exist for the page?

Comment: The value is just not printing. And yes the custom key is filled into the page. Is there a setting where I have to enable custom fields for pages? Maybe..?

Comment: my above code will just return. for printing you need to echo what you receive like `echo get_metadata('page', $postid, 'teaser-text, true);`

Comment: Yeah I've been using `echo`.. It's very strange issue...

Comment: I'm getting a false boolean output from the function call.. it's just not reading the custom fields or something.

Comment: i was doing wrong. get_metadata() can't accept 'post'. sorry! but the code `get_post_meta($postid, 'teaser-text', true)` and `get_metadata('post', $postid, 'teaser-text', true)` are working at my end! please make sure $postid is not empty! i can't find any other clue :(

Comment: Solved it, I messed around a  bit more with `get_post_meta()` and it does in fact work with pages. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `get_post_meta` just calls `get_metadata` - so the former should work, and you shouldn't need to use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but try:

```
if ( is_page() ){
    $page_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'teaser-text',true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to either start the loop, then rewind it:

```
$wp_query->the_post(); // Now $post is the first post (page) in the loop
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'teaser-text', true );`
$wp_query->rewind; // This rewinds the query so the loop functions normally
```

Or just pull the ID from the first post in the query:

```
echo get_post_meta( $wp_query->posts[0]->ID, 'teaser-text', true );
```